# is there a solution for this error [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am new to laravel, i am just trying to create a laravel project through composer, the project is created, but when updting dependencies it gave me this error below:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   'http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%24de6ed8cb77cc53bdea76e3b52aa127a7e3cb93f816873e
>   de7f13eba172a9059d.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad
>   URI

please help me with a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or renaming the vendor folder and Composer.lock file. Now run composer install . This will create the vendor folder with all its new dependencies.